# Comparing previous row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the table below,

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | Start_time          | End_time            | Duration  | Event | Agent |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | 2016-05-26 12:50:10 | 2016-05-26 12:52:54 | 00:02:44  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 12:52:55 | 2016-05-26 12:56:45 | 00:03:50  | break | user1 |
*1| 2016-05-26 12:56:49 | 2016-05-26 13:27:51 | 00:31:02  | break | user1 |
*2| 2016-05-26 12:56:53 | 2016-05-26 13:13:11 | 00:16:18  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 13:13:12 | 2016-05-26 13:25:25 | 00:12:13  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 13:25:26 | 2016-05-26 13:26:23 | 00:00:57  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 13:26:24 | 2016-05-26 13:27:37 | 00:01:13  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 14:26:50 | 2016-05-26 14:30:57 | 00:04:07  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 14:30:58 | 2016-05-26 14:46:08 | 00:15:10  | break | user1 |
```

The marked rows (*) are the target. End_time of the row must be lesserthan next Start_time. There's End_time of ***1** row is greater than the Start_time of ***2** row. In this case I need to **DETELE** that ***1** row!.. How can I delete the rows like this using Mysql query.

After deleting that rows, I need table like this,

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | Start_time          | End_time            | Duration  | Event | Agent |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | 2016-05-26 12:50:10 | 2016-05-26 12:52:54 | 00:02:44  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 12:52:55 | 2016-05-26 12:56:45 | 00:03:50  | break | user1 |
*2| 2016-05-26 12:56:53 | 2016-05-26 13:13:11 | 00:16:18  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 13:13:12 | 2016-05-26 13:25:25 | 00:12:13  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 13:25:26 | 2016-05-26 13:26:23 | 00:00:57  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 13:26:24 | 2016-05-26 13:27:37 | 00:01:13  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 14:26:50 | 2016-05-26 14:30:57 | 00:04:07  | break | user1 |
  | 2016-05-26 14:30:58 | 2016-05-26 14:46:08 | 00:15:10  | break | user1 |
```

Comment: This result is `order by` `Start_time`?

Comment: Please show us your expected output.  Is this a gaps and islands problem?

Comment: Yes result is order by Start_time @Reno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: ( assuming Start_time is sequential and unique) replace Start_time with ID if it present.

```
delete * from atable where Start_time in ( select b.Start_time
from atable a 
inner join atable b 
on a.Agent=b.Agent 
and a.Event=b.Event 
and a.Start_Time > b.Start_Time
Where b.End_time > a.Start_Time
```

Comment: I need to delete rows like that @kostas

Comment: This is great! @kostas